# How to handle wstring with NodeJS's N-API?

Tags: c++, node.js, wstring, n-api

Does the NodeJS N-API have any concept or support for C++ `wstring`? I can't find entries for something like

```
Napi::WString
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/string.md) makes no mention of a `WString`. But `wstring` is commonly used on Windows APIs. I'm curious how it's typically handled?

Comment: I think you can interoperate with utf16 LE strings.  e.g.:  https://github.com/uriegel/extension-fs/blob/066592aa93d687acdf467b22849b4236c91b5f37/wstring.h

Answer (score 1):

Napi types match the internal V8 types - and there is only one internal string type - which happens to use UTF-16 encoding. There are multiple definitions for `Napi::String::New` and one of them expects a `char16_t *` input. If your encoding is the same - which is usually the case for 16 bit chars - then you don't need anything else. But still, take care because `wchar` does not specify an encoding - only a character size.